# YOAST Seo xmlsitemap menu item not showing in the dashboard

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

2 days ago I have updated YOAST seo plugin in my WordPress website. All of a sudden the xml sitemap menu disappeared from the dashboard following this update.

Any one have any thoughts?

Note:I do not think so this is because of any conflict between other plugins or theme as  it was working fine till 2 days ago.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoast Seo  was changed their options in version 7.0. Sitemap was one of their changes.If you need to exclude some post,pages,etc from sitemap, you need to set it as noindex
More info [here](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-7-0/)